# Is it possible to set a gnuplot label relative to both the graph and the data?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a line chart where I would like to place a label with coordinates that are based on (x,y), where:

```
x would be relative to the graph at position (x = 0.01)
y would be relative to the data at position (value = 32)
```

Is it possible to display this label where it would "float" vertically depending on whether 32 is in the current yrange (in other words, if yMin < 32 < yMax, the label would be displayed, elsewise not)--such that the result would look roughly like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.  What was tripping me up was how Gnuplot handles floating point calculations. Where I was expecting a fractional value, in reality I was getting zero.  The key to my problem was the notation that Gnuplot needs in order to "think" in floating point terms:

```
stats dataFileForecast using 2 nooutput
freezeWarning   = 32.
Yhigh           = STATS_max + 10.
Ylow            = STATS_min - 10.
freezeLabel     = ((freezeWarning-Ylow) / (Yhigh-Ylow))

set yrange [Ylow:Yhigh]
if (32 > Ylow) set label "32°" at graph 0.01,freezeLabel tc rgb "#FFFFFF" font ",8"
```

The key is the 'dot' notation of the integers used in the formula to allow for the floating point calculation (someone else perhaps can explain to me why this is necessary...) The label plot coordinates are between 0 and 1 (so the middle would be 0.5) thus the need for fractional answers.

The formula "freezeLabel" computes the percentage above or below the x axis where 32 will be plotted based on the plot Yrange scale. If 32 is less than Ylow, the label won't plot (the if statement) but the math would work and just plot the label at a negative Y value (and thus, unseen.)

[image]

Comment: That's standard integer division, that you find in many programming languages `1/2 = 0`, `1.0/2.0 = 0.5`

Comment: Thanks @Christoph -- but that's not a why.  <grin>  I guess I don't think of Gnuplot scripting as a programming language.  Clearly I should start.

Comment: The why is, that gnuplot follows C conventions, where `1/2` isn't a floating point calculation since it contains only integers.

Comment: Thanks @Christoph.  I guess I just find it hard to imagine cases where '1 / 2 = 0' is the preferred outcome.